# Error mapping field in Morphia

Tags: scala, morphia

When i try to save Campaign instance with save method in Morphia. I got error mapping field exception. How can i fix it?

```
Error mapping field:Campaign.adgroups

@Entity(value = "campaign", noClassnameStored = true)
class Campaign {
  @Id
  var id = new ObjectId
  var name = ""
  var uid = new ObjectId
  var adgroups = new ListBuffer[AdGroup]
  var created_at = ""
  var comment = ""
}

@Entity(value = "ad", noClassnameStored = true)
class Ad{
  @Id
  var id = new ObjectId
  var name = ""
  var uid = new ObjectId
  var ads = new ListBuffer[Ad]
  var created_at = ""
  var comment = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morphia doesn't know what Scala's ListBuffer is.  You'll need to provide a Converter for that type.  Once that's done you tell morphia about it like so:

```
morphia.getMapper().getConverters().addConverter(ListBufferConverter.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, how to write that ListBufferConverter?

Comment: There's a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/morphia/RJy8HIRXOL0) on the mailiing list that has an example or two.  I don't know Scala/ListBuffer well enough to bang out a rough example.  The Converter API is pretty simple, though.